# Debug vue.js components in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vuejs3

I am new to Vue.js and I want to debug an application with VS Code. I simply click on the [link in the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIDYr.png)
Debugging already works with normal .js files but not with vue components (.vue).
When I set a breakpoint I get "Unbound breakpoint".
There are also [suggestions in VS Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQNE0.png)

Can someone tell me how I can setup debugging for vue components in VS Code?

I read with sourceMap and sourceMapPathOverrides, but nothing worked.